# Spark SQL execution in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a following data(alldata) which has SQL query and viewname name.

```
Select_Query|viewname
select v1,v2 from conditions|cond
select w1,w2 from locations|loca
```

I have split and properly assigned it to the temptable(alldata)

```
val Select_Querydf = spark.sql("select Select_Query,ViewName from alldata")
```

while I try to execute the query and register a tempview or table out of it, its showing nullpointer error. But the PRINTLN shows all the values in the table right when I comment out the spark.sql stmt.

```
 Select_Querydf.foreach{row => 
          val Selectstmt = row(0).toString()
          val viewname = row(1).toString()
          println(Selectstmt+"-->"+viewname)
      spark.sql(Selectstmt).registerTempTable(viewname)//.createOrReplaceTempView(viewname)
       }
```

```
output:
select v1,v2 from conditions-->cond
select w1,w2 from locations-->loca
```

But while I execute it with spark.sql, it shows the following error, Please help where I am going wrong.

> 19/12/09 02:43:12 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0
>   (TID 4) java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)    at
>   **sparkscalacode1.SQLQueryexecutewithheader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SQLQueryexecutewithheader.scala:36)
>     at
>   sparkscalacode1.SQLQueryexecutewithheader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SQLQueryexecutewithheader.scala:32)**
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 19/12/09 02:43:12 ERROR
>   TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor
>   driver): java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)    at
>   sparkscalacode1.SQLQueryexecutewithheader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SQLQueryexecutewithheader.scala:36)
>     at
>   sparkscalacode1.SQLQueryexecutewithheader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SQLQueryexecutewithheader.scala:32)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: You simply can't do that since you can't execute driver's code inside an executor. The executor doesn't know anything about spark session and/or context therefore you get the exception. The only place you can use the code like `spark.sql(Selectstmt).registerTempTable(viewname)//.createOrReplaceTempView(viewname)` is the driver

Comment: Thanks Alexandros. But could you suggest me an approach for this. I have a dataframe with 5 rows of 5 different sql queries. If I have to execute it one after the other, how to do it? But I hope its in the driver code. Let me paste the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the `spark.sql` which is `SparkSession` cannot be used in `foreach` of Dataframe. `Sparksession` is created in Driver and `foreach` is executed in worker and not serialized.

I hope the you have a small list for `Select_Querydf`, if so you can collect as a list and use it as below.

```
Select_Querydf.collect().foreach { row =>
  val Selectstmt = row.getString(0)
  val viewname = row.getString(1)
  println(Selectstmt + "-->" + viewname)
  spark.sql(Selectstmt).createOrReplaceTempView(viewname)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, it worked.. new to spark, trying to do some self project. Thanks a ton..